# Proper use of comma in a sentence

Tags: editing, punctuation

I would like to know if this sentence is right – or are there too many commas?

> His father, Sandul, clad in his brown loose-fitting, collarless,
>   ankle-length traditional jalabiya walked through the entrance,
>   followed by his herd of goats, sheep and two cattle.

This seems to have too many commas to me but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for an opinion. I have one. It can be neither right nor wrong, but it might be useful.

I do not think that you have too much punctuation. In fact, you might not have enough. I am a believer in the Oxford comma, and, as such, believe that there should be a comma after sheep. I would also add a comma after the word jalabiya to reflect that fact that a speaker of the sentence would likely pause to separate jalabiya  from the verb walked. That is, Sandul is walking not the jalabiya  that Sandul is wearing. In most cases, reading the material out loud will give you clues as to where the punctuation should appear. So, not too much punctuation.

However, what you might have is the wrong kind of punctuation and the wrong sentence structure.

If I were writing this sentence I might write it as follows:

His father, Sandul — clad in his brown loose-fitting, collarless, ankle-length traditional jalabiya — walked through the entrance, followed by his herd of goats, sheep and two cattle.

I have replaced the two commas bracketing the descriptive phrase with em dashes. If I were to read this sentence out loud, I would pause a bit longer on each em dash than I would on a comma. The em-dash is not used enough. I think of it as a super comma. You could also use parentheses but I suspect that might well be a punctuation too far.

The other choice is to break the sentence into two or more sentences. For example,

His father, Sandul, walked through the entrance. He was clad in his brown loose-fitting, collarless, ankle-length traditional jalabiya. His herd of goats, sheep and two cattle followed.

Not quite the same tone here, but this presentation might serve the story better (or worse) than the other presentations. Your choice as the writer, once you figure out what tone you are striving for.

But, I have to note, the same amount of punctuation.

Comment: I like this first suggestion. I am curious to know if you do work as an editor and if you do can I reach out to you for a payed job to help me?

Comment: I edit my own work, but not that of others. I am a retired software engineer and am trying to turn my life-long interest in reading and language into writing fiction. I do this to keep my brain in working order not to make money.

Comment: The use of dashes, and the splitting into three sentences demonstrate far better style choices. //  But if one assumes that the sheep should not be amalgamated into the herd of goats, one needs 'His herd of goats, his sheep and two X'. // You realise that 'If I were writing this sentence I might write it as follows: Y' indicates that you might drop the Oxford comma? [There's a fine treatment of the Oxford comma here somewhere, which shows that it is sometimes the preferred choice, sometimes a bad choice.] // '...two X' should be ... 'two cows / oxen / beasts / neat (archaic) / head of cattle'.

Comment: A valid point, but the question was on punctuation. I think that it is important in answers these questions to not wander too far from the central question.

Comment: 'If I were writing this sentence I might write it as follows:

"His father, Sandul — clad in his brown loose-fitting, collarless, ankle-length traditional jalabiya — walked through the entrance, followed by his herd of goats, sheep and two cattle." endorses your approval of 'two cattle'.